# Deploying application in Jboss AS 7.1 with JDK 7 getting Error as "MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./"

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

```
08:49:26,415 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child container with name  already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1549) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$1900(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1741) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more

08:49:26,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SampleApp.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service"}}
08:49:26,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SampleApp.war in 75ms
08:49:26,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service

08:49:26,709 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service"}}}}
```

Comment: Is this the complete stack trace?

Comment: I added the whole log in the description itself

Comment: There is no question here just a stack trace with an error.

Comment: I'm far from sure, but it looks like you're trying to deploy two applications/modules/libraries with the same runtime name on that host

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. Thanks Aaron and James.  Added in jboss-web.xml file

/ which resolved the issue.